# Group By In Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm using Flow and am trying to achieve the following.
I'm accessing a custom object (Invoice) and would like a count of those records (with status = paid) for each Account. If the count is > 3, I would update a checkbox on the Account record.

I was thinking about performing a 'group by' by Account on the Invoice object and loop through that, but couldn't see how to do any grouping in Flow.

Any thoughts?

Comment: [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) can do this for you. No code.

Comment: I want to schedule and launch this flow via Process Builder so it runs every hour or day without manual intervention.  Is DLRS still an option?  Can I build it into Flow?

Comment: DLRS can provide real-time rollups. Scheduling is not required in many cases, including this one.

Comment: Thanks David.  However, I'd still like to know if it's possible to perform a 'Group By' within flow.  Another element of the process is that I'd be creating records in another custom object.

Answer (score 0):

DLRS, magnificent as it was for so many of us, is now a bit redundant with Salesforce's Spring 20 release of [Before Update](https://jenwlee.com/2020/02/07/run-flows-on-record-changes-before-save-updates/) and [After Update](https://jenwlee.com/2020/06/01/after-a-record-is-saved-flow-trigger-an-alternative-to-process-builder/) flow components.

In the above situation instead of re-calculating everything every hour, it would be better to use the after-update flow each time the status of an invoice is changed.